# How can i change Popup Content ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have Bootstrap modal popup:

```
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                 <button data-dismiss="modal" class="close"><span>&times;</span></button>
                <div class="modal-title"> Links </div>                  
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
               <ul>
                   <li>@Html.ActionLink("Links", "Links", "Home")</li>
               </ul>
            </div>                
        </div>
    </div>
```

when i click links i want change popup content to action result.

How can I do?

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you may try injecting the action result via jQuery AJAX using the `show.bs.modal` event of Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant do it with ActionLink. U can use a button like below:

```
<pre>
    <input type="button" id="btnChange" />
</pre>
```

And then you can simply write html content to model content on js side like below:

```
$(".modal-body").html("yeni içerik");
```

Answer (score 0):

In this you can take help of javascript to display div on particular action.
For Example

```
    <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                     <button data-dismiss="modal" class="close"><span>&times;</span></button>
                    <div class="modal-title"> Links </div>                  
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
              <div id="dvFirst">
                 /*Your first Content*/
              </div>
             <div id="dvSecond">
                 /*Your first Content*/
             </div>
                </div>                
            </div>
        </div>

Your java-script should be like below;

<script>
 function SetPopup(id) {
if(id == "First")
{
$('#dvFirst').show();
$('#dvSecond').hide();
        $("#myModal").modal();
       }
else
{
$('#dvFirst').hide();
$('#dvSecond').show();
 $("#myModal").modal();
}

    }
</script>
```

call this javascript function from your click event.

Comment: my content came from db

Comment: so that is easy to display here from db. first you call that content and after that open this popup

Comment: you can directly call function from db on view page using @{ } sign